# Why does this stored procedure work with one query but not another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I modified a stored procedure i found to send have a list of of values as a parameter is SSRS. The user simply enters values one after another seperated by commas "2444,2445,2446,...". The stored procedure works perfectly as expected with one of my queries, but when i changed the query that it uses but not the logic of the stored procedure it no longer works... Seems strange as the logic of the stored procedure has nothing to do with the query itself.

Here is the working Stored procedure

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MULTI_VALUED_USER_INPUT_PARAMETER]    Script Date: 4/28/2017 10:22:55 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/*CREATING A STORED PROCEDURE, WHICH HAS ONE INPUT PARAMETER*/
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MULTI_VALUED_USER_INPUT_PARAMETER](@DIESECTION VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
  /*CHECKING IF TABLE EXISTS IN THE DATABASE*/
  IF OBJECT_ID('TEMP', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    /*IF TABLE EXISTS THEN DROPPING AND RECREATING TABLE*/
    DROP TABLE TEMP

  CREATE TABLE TEMP (DIESECTION VARCHAR(MAX))

  /*INSERTING EACH COMMA SEPERATED VALUE INTO TEMP TABLE*/
  WHILE CHARINDEX(',',@DIESECTION)<>0
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES((SELECT LEFT(@DIESECTION, CHARINDEX(',',@DIESECTION)-1)))
    SET @DIESECTION=(SELECT RIGHT(@DIESECTION,LEN(@DIESECTION)-CHARINDEX(',',@DIESECTION)))
  END

  /*MODIFY QUERY TO FIT YOUR NEEDS!*/
  SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100000 p.id AS DIE_SECTION,SUM(r.CALC_QTY) AS GROSS_KG, COUNT(WO.BASE_ID) AS NUMBER_OF_TIMES_ORDERED, MAX(WO.CREATE_DATE) AS RECENT_ORDER_DATE,
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(P.USER_3) = 1 
        THEN Convert(varchar(50), CONVERT(decimal(14,3), P.USER_3))
    END AS KG_M

  FROM [DAJCOR].[dbo].[WORK_ORDER] wo JOIN REQUIREMENT R ON R.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = wo.BASE_ID JOIN PART P ON P.ID = WO.DRAWING_ID  
  WHERE P.USER_3 IS NOT NULL 
  AND r.PART_ID = WO.DRAWING_ID 
  AND WO.BASE_ID <> WO.PART_ID
  AND P.ID IN(SELECT DIESECTION FROM TEMP)
  AND (WO.CREATE_DATE BETWEEN convert(datetime, '2009-01-01') AND GETDATE())
  GROUP BY P.ID, P.USER_3 ORDER BY COUNT(WO.BASE_ID)

  /*DROPPING THE TEMP TABLE*/
  DROP TABLE TEMP
END
```

And this second one uses the exact same stored procedure with a slightly more complex query. But the store procedure should only be affecting the first argument of the WHERE clause.

```
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MULTI_VALUED_USER_INPUT_PARAMETER]    Script Date: 4/28/2017 9:49:02 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO
/*CREATING A STORED PROCEDURE, WHICH HAS ONE INPUT PARAMETER*/
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MULTI_VALUED_USER_INPUT_PARAMETER_NET_KG](@DIESECTION VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN

  /*CHECKING IF TABLE EXISTS IN THE DATABASE*/
  IF OBJECT_ID('TEMP', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    /*IF TABLE EXISTS THEN DROPPING AND RECREATING TABLE*/
    DROP TABLE TEMP

  CREATE TABLE TEMP (DIESECTION VARCHAR(MAX))

  /*INSERTING EACH COMMA SEPERATED VALUE INTO TEMP TABLE*/
  WHILE CHARINDEX(',',@DIESECTION)<>0
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES((SELECT LEFT(@DIESECTION, CHARINDEX(',',@DIESECTION)-1)))
    SET @DIESECTION=(SELECT RIGHT(@DIESECTION,LEN(@DIESECTION)-CHARINDEX(',',@DIESECTION)))
  END

  /*MODIFY QUERY TO FIT YOUR NEEDS!*/
 SELECT DISTINCT LT.WORKORDER_BASE_ID,WO.DRAWING_ID,P.WEIGHT AS SHIPPING_WEIGHT,
    CASE
    WHEN R.SUBORD_WO_SUB_ID >= 0
    THEN P.WEIGHT/R.QTY_PER
    ELSE P.WEIGHT
    END AS NET_WEIGHT
,R.PART_ID,LT.GOOD_QTY,
LT.GOOD_QTY * CASE
    WHEN R.SUBORD_WO_SUB_ID >= 0
    THEN P.WEIGHT/R.QTY_PER
    ELSE P.WEIGHT
    END AS NET_KG,SUM(IT.QTY) AS GROSS_KG,LT.TRANSACTION_ID AS LT_TRANS,IT.TRANSACTION_DATE AS IT_DATE,LT.TRANSACTION_DATE AS LT_DATE
,LT.EMPLOYEE_ID,LT.RESOURCE_ID,LT.HOURS_WORKED,(LT.GOOD_QTY * CASE
    WHEN R.SUBORD_WO_SUB_ID >= 0
    THEN P.WEIGHT/R.QTY_PER
    ELSE P.WEIGHT
    END/LT.HOURS_WORKED) AS NET_KG_HR
FROM LABOR_TICKET LT JOIN INVENTORY_TRANS IT ON IT.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = LT.WORKORDER_BASE_ID LEFT JOIN WORK_ORDER WO ON WO.BASE_ID = LT.WORKORDER_BASE_ID LEFT JOIN PART P ON P.ID = WO.PART_ID
    LEFT JOIN REQUIREMENT R ON R.WORKORDER_BASE_ID = LT.WORKORDER_BASE_ID  AND R.WORKORDER_SUB_ID = WO.SUB_ID
WHERE WO.DRAWING_ID IN (SELECT DIESECTION FROM TEMP) AND LT.GOOD_QTY > 0 AND (LT.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '04-01-2017' AND '04-10-2017') AND IT.WAREHOUSE_ID <> 'COSTCODE' AND IT.PART_ID = WO.DRAWING_ID
    AND P.WEIGHT IS NOT NULL AND LT.RESOURCE_ID LIKE 'EP%' AND (R.PART_ID IN ('25023', '25024', '25025', '25026', '25027', '25028') OR R.PART_ID IS NULL) AND R.QTY_PER <> 0
GROUP BY LT.WORKORDER_BASE_ID,WO.DRAWING_ID,P.WEIGHT, 
    CASE
    WHEN R.SUBORD_WO_SUB_ID >= 0
    THEN P.WEIGHT/R.QTY_PER
    ELSE P.WEIGHT
    END,R.PART_ID,LT.GOOD_QTY, LT.GOOD_QTY * CASE
    WHEN R.SUBORD_WO_SUB_ID >= 0
    THEN P.WEIGHT/R.QTY_PER
    ELSE P.WEIGHT
    END,LT.TRANSACTION_DATE,IT.TRANSACTION_DATE,LT.TRANSACTION_ID,LT.EMPLOYEE_ID,LT.RESOURCE_ID,LT.HOURS_WORKED
ORDER BY WO.DRAWING_ID,LT.WORKORDER_BASE_ID

  /*DROPPING THE TEMP TABLE*/
  DROP TABLE TEMP
END
```

The problem is that when i try and enter values for example "23703" then nothing appears, but if i add a comma at the end "23703," then it works. Where the first example works normally for the first query but only the second example works for the 2nd query. Another example would be if i had multiple values "1,2,3" only 1 and 2 would appear because they are followed by a comma, but the 3 value would not because it does not have a comma following it.

Comment: You should add COMMA to the end of variable @DIESECTION in the both queries before to use it. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code most likely has to do with this loop: `WHILE CHARINDEX(',',@DIESECTION)<>0`. Since without a comma, it will not do anything.

However the real problem of splitting delimited strings can be solved with some other much faster solutions.

One example is a table valued function by Jeff Moden:

```
create function [dbo].[delimitedsplit8K] (
      @pstring varchar(8000)
    , @pdelimiter char(1)
  )
returns table with schemabinding as
 return
  with e1(N) as (
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1
  )
  , e2(N) as (select 1 from e1 a, e1 b)
  , e4(N) as (select 1 from e2 a, e2 b)
  , ctetally(N) as (
    select top (isnull(datalength(@pstring),0)) 
      row_number() over (order by (select null)) from e4
  )
  , ctestart(N1) as (
    select 1 union all
    select t.N+1 from ctetally t where substring(@pstring,t.N,1) = @pdelimiter
  )
  , ctelen(N1,L1) as (
    select s.N1,
      isnull(nullif(charindex(@pdelimiter,@pstring,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
    from ctestart s
  )
 select itemnumber = row_number() over(order by l.N1)
      , item       = substring(@pstring, l.N1, l.L1)
   from ctelen l
;
go
```

Which can be used like so:

```
declare @diesection varchar(8000) = '1,2,3';
select s.ItemNumber, s.Item
from [dbo].[delimitedsplit8K](@diesection,',') s
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XJSQUS89642

returns:

```
+------------+------+
| ItemNumber | Item |
+------------+------+
|          1 |    1 |
|          2 |    2 |
|          3 |    3 |
+------------+------+
```

---

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

---

Since this is for reporting, and you are doing things where parameters may or may not be populated, you may find these articles helpful as well:

Catch-all queries reference:

- [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options - Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options)
- [Dynamic Search Conditions - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)
- [Catch-all queries - Gail Shaw](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)
- [An Updated "Kitchen Sink" Example - Aaron Bertand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/)

Comment: Wow this is really neat! thanks for this! Now i don't even need to use my stored procedure at all. VERY USEFUL SOLUTION.

Comment: Do you know off the top of your head how to return all values if the list used in an IN clause is empty? so column1 IN () then all values?

Comment: @Azuraith like this: `column1 in (select Item from dbo.delimitedsplit8K(@diesection,','))` -- Updated the rextester demo to include an example of this as well: http://rextester.com/XJSQUS89642

Comment: Yes i understand that part. But how can i return ALL values from the query if the column1 in (...) returns no values. So if no values are found in column1 IN (...) then return ALL values. 

Similarly, you can do Column LIKE '%name%' to find everything with name in it. Or you can do Column LIKE '%%' will return every value.

Comment: @Azuraith How about: `... and (column1 in (select Item from dbo.delimitedsplit8K(@diesection,',')) or @diesection = '')`

Comment: @Azuraith Also updated my answer with some references for catch-all queries. [An Updated "Kitchen Sink" Example - Aaron Bertand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/) would be a good one to start with.

Comment: Ended up using a case in my where clause to get the effect i wanted

`WHERE (
CASE
 WHEN @diesection <> ''
 THEN WO.DRAWING_ID 
END IN (select S.ITEM  from [dbo].[delimitedsplit8K] (@diesection,',') s)
OR
CASE
 WHEN @diesection = ''
 THEN WO.DRAWING_ID
END LIKE '%%')`